# next() vs Single() Which one is effective?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I want cast to mono from flux. However, I can't decide when to use `single()` or `next()` and don't know which one is more effective?

```
Flux<String> optionalIdsFlux = Flux
    .fromIterable(result.getPersonalizationEntity())
    .filter(i -> i.getKey().equals(PERSONALIZATION_KEY))
    .next()  //  or single() ??
    .map(DataEntity::getValue)
    .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);`
```

Answer (score 3):

They are actually quite different. `next()` takes the first value that is emitted and cancels the subscription afterwards.

`single()`, on the other hand, expects that exactly one element is emitted in the first place. If that's not the case, and zero or more elements are emitted, then an error signal is emitted.

Which one to choose depends on your use case. If the source is guaranteed to emit exactly one element, then you can use `single()`. Otherwise use `next()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In my case, the source is guaranteed to emit exactly one element is it inefficient to use next() ?

Comment: @MertBulut Efficiency is really not a concern here. If anything `next()` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to what `a better oliver` said, if there is a **super strong guarantee** that the `Publisher` you have only ever emits at most one `onNext`, you can turn it into a `Mono` - *without the safety belt on* - by using `Mono.fromDirect(Publisher)`.

Comment: Thank for your interest Simon.